# Any tutorials that show ajax content slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, css

I found a tutorial that is exactly the way I want the slider to look with the exception that I do not want to have multiple slides in each slide. And I simply want the text to change as I click different links.

Also I want the slides to transition by fading in.

I tried playing around with the code, but it seems to be way too complex for my understanding to fix. Because it seems to use Movefromleft movefromright .. for each movement.

I need some help to either fix this or guide me to a less complex version of a nice interface (like this) tutorial that does the same.

http://jsfiddle.net/itsnamitashetty/73pffnx9/2/

```
.mi-slider ul.mi-moveFromRight li {
-webkit-animation: moveFromRight 350ms ease-in-out both;
animation: moveFromRight 350ms ease-in-out both;
visibility:visible !important;
 }
```

I am not sure why and how to get the fiddle to show up what its doing right now. But basically it doesn;t show up the first slide, and then works for the second and third but after the first clicks it doesnt work..

here is the original tutorial

http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ItemSlider/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to find another content slider that did what I wanted but I had to make it work with the other tutorial.

[HERE is what I came up with](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hxsoq)
Unfortunately the codepen in not showing how it works.

But anyways for someone looking to achieve the same thing
here are the two tutorials that I used, 
[Item slider](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/12/31/how-to-create-a-simple-multi-item-slider/) & [Full Width Tabs](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/03/21/responsive-full-width-tabs/)

I basically worked around the CSS of Full Width Tabs to make it interface pretty much like Item slider

```
    .container {
        font-family: 'Lato', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
        color: #47a3da;
    }

    a {text-decoration: none;
        outline: none;}


    *, *:after, *:before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    }
    .container{width:60%; margin:2% 20%;}

    .tabs {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 1em 0 2em;
        font-weight: 300;
    }

    /* Nav */
    .tabs nav {
        text-align: center;
        border-top: 5px solid transparent;
    }


    .tabs nav a.tab-current {
    /*  border: 1px solid #47a3da;
        box-shadow: inset 0 2px #47a3da;*/
        border-bottom: none;
        z-index: 100;
    }




    .tabs nav a {
    display: inline-block;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        letter-spacing: 5px;
        padding: 40px 30px 30px 34px;
        position: relative;
        color: #888;
        outline: none;
        -webkit-transition: color 0.2s linear;
        transition: color 0.2s linear;
    }


    .tabs nav a:hover, .tabs nav a.tab-current  {
        color: #000;
    }



    .content{background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8)}
    /* Content */
    .content section {
        font-size: 1.25em;
        padding: 3em 1em;
        display: none;
        max-width: 1230px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .content section:before,
    .content section:after {
        content: '';
        display: table;
    }

    .content section:after {
        clear: both;
    }

    /* Fallback example */
    .no-js .content section {
        display: block;
        padding-bottom: 2em;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #47a3da;
    }

    .content section.content-current {
        display: block;
    }



    nav a.tab-current:after,
    nav a.tab-current:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: -5px;
        border: solid transparent;
        height: 0;
        width: 0;
        position: absolute;
        pointer-events: none;
    }


    nav a.tab-current:after {
        border-color: transparent;
        border-top-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        border-width: 20px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -20px;
    }

    nav a.tab-current:before {
        border-color: transparent;
        border-width: 27px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -27px;
    }
```